# How can I mark a package as obsolete with setup.py?

Tags: python, setup.py

I am using distutils (setup.py) to create rpm-packages from my python projects. Now, one of my projects which had a very specific task (say png-creation) is moved to a more general project (image-toolkit).

1. Is there a way to tell the user that the old package (png-creation) is obsolete when he/she installs the new package (image-toolkit).
2. Is there a way to make a new version of the old package (png-creation) which tells the user that he/she should use the new package (image-toolkit) instead?

These are two different scenarios from which the first one would be my favorite. In both scenarios I assume that a user has installed my package (png-creation) with his package manager.

In the first (my favorite) scenario the following would happen:

- The user runs an update with his package manager.
- The package manager recognizes that png-creation is obsolete and that image-toolkit has to be installed instead. So the package manger removes png-creation and installs image-toolkit.

If this scenario is not possible, the second one would be:

- I tell my users that they have to install image-toolkit.
- The user runs install image-toolkit with his package manager.
- The package manager recognizes that png-creation is not needed anymore and removes it.

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna use the version number which can prevent the package from being installed and will let know the one installing it that the version specified is required.

Something like this.

```
requires = ['setuptools ==0.8',
            'transaction==1.4.1']
```

Comment: But how does that help me? I know, that I could specify that installing a package requires (at least) a specified version of another package. But how can I specify, that installing one package makes another package obsolete? Or better yet, how could I specify that updating a package leads to the deinstallation of this package and to the installation of another package?

Answer (score 0):

You can mark packages as obsolete:
https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#relationships-between-distributions-and-packages

However, this may simply uninstall (replace) existing packages without warning.